# KDE Konsole to select text and copy to clipboard

Tags: kde, konsole

In Ubuntu Terminal, drag and drop selection can copy the text selected into clipboard and Shift+Insert to paste. In KDE Konsole, it seems selection doesn't do copy. So either I have to use mouse middle key to copy/paste, or open context menu to click on `copy`. Is there any way to configure Konsole to do copy selection? Or any keyboard shortcut to do copy?

Comment: Hi stan, @Per Lundberg. Did you find out a way to copy on select in KDE? I am also searching for the same.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Konsole can copy with `ctrl + shift + c`, and paste with `ctrl + shift + v`. My right click context menu on Konsole 2.7.4, KDE 4.7.4, Kubuntu 11.10, tells me these keyboard shortcuts.

Edit: There is actually a secondary buffer. Selected text is automatically added to this buffer, and middle click automatically pastes it. `ctrl + shift + insert` will also paste from this buffer. This can be changed under `Settings` > `Configure Shortcuts` > `Paste Selection`. `ctrl + insert` defaults to an alternate for normal copy, and `shift + insert` defaults to an alternate for normal paste.

Comment: Thanks, great to hear about the secondary buffer @Bob. Is there any way to get Konsole to automatically copy to the default clipboard on selection?

Comment: @PerLundberg Not that I'm aware of, but I have not used Konsole in years. You're probably better off asking a new question.

Comment: On a fresh Kubuntu 20.4 install, Ctrl+Insert doesn't do anything but echo `5~`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, I just hit this. Had to manually configure the shortcut to Ctrl+Ins.

Answer (score 9):

Settings > Manage Profiles > New Profile > Mouse > "Copy on select"

Comment: Can also be set on standard profile instead of creating a new profile

Comment: @yasd - as of Fedora 38 the "standard" profile is called "Built-in" and is read only. You have to create one and set it as default.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Settings" in the Menu. Select "Configure Shortcuts". Search for "Copy" and "Paste". For each you then assign the desired shortcut by first clicking on the entry in the shortcut editor, clicking on "Custom" and then pressing `ctrl - c` and `ctrl - v`, respectively.

However, I would advise against using `ctrl - c`, because normally this is bound to send a `SIGINT` signal to an application in the terminal. This can become usefull if an application in the terminal needs to be aborted. The way these terminal control keys are handled can also be configured in Konsole. For this you go to "Settings", then "Manage Profiles", then "Edit Profile".  Here you click on the "Keyboard" tab, where you then can edit the existing configurations or add a new one.

Comment: `Ctrl+C` generally sends `SIGINT`, not `SIGTERM` (calling `kill` without specifying a signal will send `SIGTERM`). The signal that is sent can be relevant if an application has implemented a signal handler. Some applications will catch `SIGINT` and/or `SIGTERM` and shut down gracefully. `SIGKILL` cannot be caught, so `kill -9` is the guaranteed way to stop a misbehaving application (and maybe lose data).

Comment: I edited the answer, so now it correctly states `SIGINT`.

Comment: In the IntelliJ idea terminal, it's possible to use `CTRL+C` to send a `SIGINT` if nothing is selected, or copy when selecting text. Is there a way to keep this behavior in konsole?