# kde > how to copy a block of text like I would in gnome-terminal

Tags: kde, copy-paste, konsole

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KDE Konsole to select text and copy to clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/399509/kde-konsole-to-select-text-and-copy-to-clipboard)

In gnome-terminal, I used ctrl + mouse click > mouse drag to highlight a block of text.

Then I can use Ctrl + Shift + c / Ctrl + Shift + v.

How can I do this same thing in Konsole?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  The answer to this question, I found, is to use Ctrl+Alt + ( Mouse Click > Mouse Drag ) to highlight a block of text.

Answer (score 0):

> Konsole can copy with ctrl + shift + c, and paste with ctrl + shift + v. My right click context menu on Konsole 2.7.4, KDE 4.7.4, Kubuntu 11.10, tells me these keyboard shortcuts.
>
> Edit: There is actually a secondary buffer. Selected text is
>   automatically added to this buffer, and middle click automatically
>   pastes it. ctrl + shift + insert will also paste from this buffer.
>   This can be changed under Settings > Configure Shortcuts > Paste
>   Selection. ctrl + insert defaults to an alternate for normal copy, and
>   shift + insert defaults to an alternate for normal paste.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/399509/kde-konsole-to-select-text-and-copy-to-clipboard).